# "Big union" of the power set of $\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$
\bigcup\limits_\mathscr{x \in P(\mathbb{N})} x
$$

An interesting question that came up on my elementary set & logic class, and I was wondering if my logic is correct on the matter. I essentially broke the problem down.

We know that the power set of $\mathbb{N}$ is $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{N}) = \{\emptyset, \{ 1\}, \{1,2\}, \cdots\}$, therefore we have:

$$\bigcup\limits_\mathscr{x \in \{\emptyset, \{ 1\}, \{1,2\}, \cdots\}} x$$

Thus, we can assume the problem is asking for:

$$
\emptyset \cup \{1\} \cup \{1,2\} \cup \{ 1,2,3 \} \cup \cdots
$$

This is equal to all the natural numbers in its set format:

$$
\{ 1, 2, 3, \cdots\}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\bigcup\limits_\mathscr{x \in P(\mathbb{N})} x = \mathbb{N}
$$

I believe my logic is correct, but I wanted to double check with the folks here.

**Disclaimer: This is assuming $\mathbb{N}$ begins at $1$.**

Comment: I image you mean $\bigcup\limits_{x \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})} x$? If yes, you’re right.

Comment: Literally fixed this seconds before you replied -- yup, that's what I meant. :) Awesome, thank you, I just needed confirmation I wasn't missing anything else.

Comment: In set theory we write $\cup S$ to mean $\{y:\exists x\in S\,(y\in x)\}.$ If $S$ is indexed by some set $J,$ as $S=\{s_j:j\in J\}$ then $\cup S=\cup_{s\in S}\,s=\cup_{j\in J}\,s_j. $ The notation $S=\{s_j:j\in J\}$ means that we have a  function $ f$ with domain $J$, and that we are writing $s_j$ for $f(j)$. But we don't always need to describe $S$ as the image of some function.

Comment: I have  reluctantly conformed to the convention on this site that $\Bbb N=\Bbb Z^+.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer to the problem is correct and also your idea of how a proof might work, but I think you can be more rigorous.

Let $n \in \bigcup_{x\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})} x$, then clearly there is a $x\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ such that $n\in x$. By definition $x\subseteq \mathbb{N}$, which implies $n\in \mathbb{N}$. So $\bigcup_{x\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})} x\subseteq \mathbb{N}$

On the other hand $\mathbb{N} \in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$, which yields $\bigcup_{x\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})} x \supseteq \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I am a CS major and decided to take this class to gain better knowledge on proofs, and we are slowly building up to that. For now, the intentions weren't "proof" per se, but more so "what's the logical answer."

Comment: Regardless, I appreciate the writting, and will study it up. Thank you!

Comment: I have no idea what a CS major is, but you can start to get used to this way of proving set equalities, because this is a very standard procedure of doing it properly.

Comment: Computer science -- and will do, I appreciate it.